# How can I get the value of a textbox by using an array element's value?

Tags: c#

I have 14 fields that all accept the same data types to be used with a particular function.  I want to avoid having to use the contents of my current for loop 14 times.  I need to find a way to get a textbox object by using the value of an array element as the textbox's reference.  E.G. array[i].Text.  How can I do something like this?

Use the following as a brief example:

```
if(grades[0] != assignmentEarnedTB[i].Text && grades[1] != assignmentPossTB[i].Text){
```

As expected, the above code gives an error string does not contain a definition for Text.

Here is the rest of the code to show you what I mean...

```
string[] assignmentNames = {"Assignment 1", "Assignment 2", "Assignment 3", "Assignment 4", "Assignment 5", "Assignment 6", "Assignment 7", "Assignment 8", "Assignment 9", "Assignment 10", "Quiz 1", "Quiz 2", "Midterm Project", "Final Project"};
string[] assignmentEarnedTB = {"txtAsmt1Earned", "txtAsmt2Earned", "txtAsmt3Earned", "txtAsmt4Earned", "txtAsmt5Earned", "txtAsmt6Earned", "txtAsmt8Earned", "txtAsmt9Earned", "txtAsmt10Earned", "txtQuiz1Earned", "txtQuiz2Earned", "txtMidtermEarned", "txtFinalEarned"};
string[] assignmentPossTB = {"txtAsmt1Poss","txtAsmt2Poss", "txtAsmt3Poss", "txtAsmt4Poss", "txtAsmt5Poss", "txtAsmt6Poss", "txtAsmt7Poss", "txtAsmt8Poss", "txtAsmt9Poss", "txtAsmt10Poss", "txtQuiz1Poss", "txtQuiz2Poss", "txtMidtermPoss", "txtFinalPoss"};

for(int i = 0; i < assignmentNames.Length; i++){

    string gradeString = proxy.GetAssignmentScore(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]), assignmentNames[i]);
    string[] grades = gradeString.Split("/");

    if(grades[0] != assignmentEarnedTB[i].Text && grades[1] != assignmentPossTB[i].Text){
        if(txtAsmt1Earned.Text != "" && txtAsmt1Poss.Text != "" && ){
            if (Convert.ToInt32(txtAsmt1Earned.Text) < Convert.ToInt32(txtAsmt1Poss.Text))
            {
                proxy.UpdateAssignmentScore(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]), "Assignment 1", Convert.ToInt32(txtAsmt1Earned.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtAsmt1Poss.Text));
            }
            else
            {
                proxy.AddAssignmentScore(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]), "Assignment 1", Convert.ToInt32(txtAsmt1Earned.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtAsmt1Poss.Text));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which stack is this, web or desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of keeping the names of your `TextBoxes` in `assignmentEarnedTB` and `assignmentPossTB`, keep the `TextBox` references themselves.

```
TextBox[] assignmentEarnedTB = new [] { txtAsmt1Earned, txtAsmt2Earned, ... }
```

Your current implementation is only keeping `string` objects whose value are the same as the names of your `TextBox` objects. You have no logic to dictate that you want to access the control that is named `assignmentEarnedTB[i]`. Doing it this way correctly is a little cumbersome, so, it's better to take it a step upward and instead keep a collection of your `TextBox` objects rather than the names of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that I can fully recall the object names for this stuff, but the nature of this approach would suffice:

```
Control[] assignmentEarnedTB = { txtAsmt1Earned, txtAsmt2Earned, txtAsmt3Earned, ... };
Control[] assignmentPossTB = { txtAsmt1Poss, txtAsmt2Poss, txtAsmt3Poss, ... };
```

So by arraying the actual object references, your code using integer subscript starts to work.